# Image on Image like Facebook

Tags: image

I would like to put an image on another image like it is done in Facebook, Google+ and now Twitter.

Large back image with a smaller one on the left side dropping off the large one, if that makes sence

Comment: <div style='position: absolute; width: 130px; height: 130px; z-index: 1; left: 840px; top: 450px'; >
<img title='Logo Name' height='130' src='images/logo.png' width='130'/>
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several ways you can do this, 1 of them is using position (so you're on the right track).

Place 2 images inside an element that has `position:relative` and place the top image `position:absolute`, like so:

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <img alt="" src="foreground.jpg" />
    <img alt="" style="position:absolute; left:40px; top:20px" src="background.jpg" /> 
</div>
```

Check out this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EmLqL/3/)

Another way would be to have the background image set as a background on the `<div>` and place the image you want on top directly inside that div. Check out this 2nd [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EmLqL/4/)